# After iOS 13.4.1 update WKWebView not able to recognise tap gesture

Tags: wkwebview, swift5, xcode11, ios13.4

After ios update to 13.4.1 to able to detect tap gesture in WKWebView, my code as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTap) )
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        webview.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
      return true
    }

@objc func viewTap() {
    print("tap on viewTap...")
}
```

Comment: found solution on this?